# How to change the value of same button in angular 2 based on different conditions

Tags: angular

I have two options i.e to Edit User and to Add New User.I am using same button at both places.I want the button value to be changed to Save when I am trying to add new user.

My template-

```
<input type="button" (click)="addNewUser()" value="Add">
```

Pseudo code in .ts-

```
addNewUser(){
if("editUser"){
//Keep the value as ADD
}
else{
//Change the value to Save
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use it as follow:

```
<input type="button" (click)="addNewUser()" [value]="editUser ? 'ADD' : 'SAVE'" />
```

See plunker http://embed.plnkr.co/lEFPmd9HS5EgZDsebA4K/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a property to your component class (e.g. value), and alter it in your if statement.

sample.component.ts

```
public value: string = 'Add';

addNewUser(){
    if("editUser"){
        //Keep the value as ADD
        this.value = 'Add';
    } else {
        //Change the value to Save
        this.value = 'Save';
    }
}
```

sample.component.html

```
<input type="button" (click)="addNewUser()" value="{{ value }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<input type="button" (click)="addNewUser()" value="{{ value }}">
```

In your component:

```
public value: string = 'Add';

addNewUser() {
    if("editUser") {
        //Keep the value as ADD
        this.value = "Add";
    } else {
        //Change the value to Save
        this.value = "Save";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="button" (click)="addNewUser()" value="ADD" id="btn">

  addNewUser(){
    let btnTxt = (document.getElementById('btn').value).toLocaleLowerCase();
    if(btnTxt === 'add'){
      document.getElementById('btn').value = 'EDIT';
    }else{
      document.getElementById('btn').value = 'ADD';
    }
  }
```